# LoRaWAN Coverage Design in Rural Areas

Tags: lora, lorawan

I need to cover a district with a LoRaWAN network for air quality sensors. I know that the LoRa/LoRaWAN technology is the perfect solution when Line of Sight is maintained, but is there any easy way to determine how many gateways are needed in rural areas? I amning plan to use Kerlink Wirnet iStation V1.5 as gateway and ESP32-based CO2 sensors. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Line of Sight is definitely NOT needed for LoRa or LoRaWAN.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't need line of site for LoRa communication.

The easiest, and most accurate way to estimate the number of required gateways is to do a field test with one single gateway and a test device (e.g.: an Adeunis Field Tester). This way you can check what the longest distance between an end device and the gateway can be. Using that information you can calculate the required density of base stations.
If you register for a free account on Actility's [ThingPark Community Portal](https://community.thingpark.org) and you connect your Kerlink gateway to the ThingPark Network Server, you will be able to use Actility's Network Survey Tool that can visualize the coverage of your gateway an a map.

If you want to make a rough estimation I would say that in a rural environment, where devices are outdoor and the gateway antenna is on a 20m height pole or on top of a 20 height building the range of a gateway is around 1-3 km. If the end devices are indoors (in rooms having windows) this range is 0.5-1.5 km.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use The Things Stack community edition (formerly known as TTN, The Things Network) in conjunction with [ttnmapper.org](https://ttnmapper.org). Note that there is currently a transition going on from TTN (V2) to The Things Stack V3, see the notice on the webpage. This method uses field tests similar to the system proposed in Norbert Herbert's answer; any simple node is sufficient because the GW's metadata are evaluated. You can track you field test live on a smartphone. As LoRaWAN coverage strongly depends on the gateway's placement, it should be at least similar to the intended position, better be the planned position proper.

For a dry run without any hardware, you may also have a look at the freeware program [Radio Mobile](http://www.ve2dbe.com/english1.html) by Roger Coudé VE2DBE, with more info by Remko Welling PE1MEW [here](http://radiomobile.pe1mew.nl/?Welcome...). The program lets you simulate radio connections in a wide variety of settings, including a complete mapping of a region with multiple gateways.

Answer (score 0):

Line of Sight is not always needed. There are many factors that will affect the reach of your modules, including the terrain (hills can get in the way, especially higher ranges), the settings you would use for your LoRa or LoRaWAN network, and where you position your gateway(s) – when using LoRaWAN – or transceivers, when using LoRa.

I live in a mixed environment, half hills and jungle and half dense, high rises, and I get about 10 km coverage, no LoS, and more if I get LoS from a height, both with LoRa and LoRaWAN, although reliability is not always guaranteed.

But first you have to decide whether you will go the LoRa or the LoRaWAN – this has implications on both the hardware and software budget: while LoRaWAN requires more equipment, and more onerous, it will simplify the setup cost, software-wise. I am very much a LoRa guy myself, but I do recognize the benefits of LoRaWAN for quick developments.

But it'd be cheap to do a first test with a couple of LoRa devices, to check how far you can reach in your region.